# Yet another `rm: cannot remove 'file': Permission denied`

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, rm

I want to remove the `.html` file from the `/home/user1/html/` directory.

I have tried nearly all of the solutions posted on a myriad of other web sites.  Nothing is working.

```
user1@comp1:~/html$ sudo rm -f .html
rm: cannot remove '.html': Permission denied
```

Properties of directory:

```
user1@comp1:~$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 4096 Aug 21 14:48 html
```

Properties of file:

```
user1@comp1:~/html$ ls -al
total 3912
-rwxrwxrwx 0 user1 user1 1365246 Aug 20 17:20 .html
```

Things I have tried on directory (all run successfully):

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ./html
sudo chmod 777 ./html
sudo chmod -R 777 ./html
```

Things I have tried on the file (all run successfully):

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER .html
sudo chmod 777 .html
sudo chmod 777 .
```

I tried looking at the file's attributes (did not run successfully):

```
user1@comp1:~/html$ lsattr .html
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on .html
```

`strace` with sudo:

```
user1@comp1:~/html$ strace sudo rm -f .html
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "rm", "-f", ".html"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
write(2, "strace: exec: Operation not perm"..., 38strace: exec: Operation not permitted
) = 38
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

`strace` without sudo:

```
user1@comp1:~/html$ strace rm -f .html
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "-f", ".html"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x805000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=39157, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 39157, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcfcb47e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcfcb470000
mmap(NULL, 3971488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcfcae30000
mprotect(0x7fcfcaff0000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fcfcb1f0000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7fcfcb1f0000
mmap(0x7fcfcb1f6000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcfcb1f6000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcfcb460000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcfcb450000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fcfcb460700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fcfcb1f0000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fcfcb425000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fcfcb47e000, 39157)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x805000
brk(0x826000)                           = 0x826000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1668976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1668976, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcfcb28d000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, ".html", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=1365246, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, ".html", 0)          = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "rm: ", 4rm: )                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove '.html'", 21cannot remove '.html')   = 21
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Permission denied", 19: Permission denied)     = 19
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `chattr -i` to make sure the immutable bit isn't set, but `lsattr` isn't working, so I would definitely run `fsck -n` to begin with.

Comment: "user1@comp1:~/html$ ls -al"  should have shown  "." and ".."   Did you leave them out.  If so, can you add them to your question?

Comment: What filesystem is that? What does `df -T ~` or `mount /home` print? (or whatever the path is) Can you [edit] that information to the question?

Comment: The `-rwxrwxrwx 0 user1 user1 1365246 Aug 20 17:20 .html` suggests the filesystem is corrupted, as the link count is zero, meaning the inode has no directory entries pointing to it... Except `.html` does. After a filesystem check, the file should appear in the `lost+found` directory, and the `.html` directory entry should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run fsck on the partition where the file is.

To do that you must boot in single mode and do something like

```
fsck.ext4 /dev/yourpartdevice
```

(or change ext4 to the partition type - and replace yourpartdevice by the partition with problem)

But... "lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on .html" looks like to be a hardware problem, and maybe fsck will be not capable of correcting the file.

If this solve your problem please mark this as the correct answer.

**UPDATE** for **other** users reading this answer:
Consider that RAM memory can do a lot of crazy things, so checking your RAM is good before running fsck, because that can make fsck to run very destructive.

Good Lucky!

Comment: `lsattr` is `ext2/ext3/ext4`-centric, so getting `Inappropriate ioctl` is perfectly normal if the filesystem isn't one of those.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THE `-y` ARGUMENT THE FIRST TIME YOU RUN FSCK OR YOU MAY CORRUPT DATA. This being said, running `fsck` with `-n` - the opposite of `-y`, is exactly the right thing to do here.**

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini Not all Linux's use ext4 by default. For example, Red Hat 7 and it's variants use xfs by default.